# PYTHONPATH Shared Library Issue

Tags: python, heatmap, python-import, pythonpath

I'm a longtime lurker, firstime poster so please be gentle.

I've been using Python for a couple of months now and I've been trying to install a library called [heatmap](https://github.com/jjguy/heatmap) specifically [this fork](https://github.com/kwauchope/heatmap/commit/32a520613f0bc018ba6932b864a9ee0a5497758b). Having installed via the zipfile, I can import heatmap just fine but I get an Exception when I try and use it:

```
Exception Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-14-ce255099c4d1> in <module>() ----> 1 map = heatmap.Heatmap()
C:\Users\Standalone\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\heatmap\heatmap\heatmap.py in __init__(self, libpath)
     94 
     95         if not self._heatmap:
---> 96             raise Exception("Heatmap shared library not found in PYTHONPATH.")
     97 
     98     def heatmap(self, points, dotsize=150, opacity=128, size=(1024, 1024), scheme="classic", area=None, 
Exception: Heatmap shared library not found in PYTHONPATH.*
```

I've tried appending to the sys.path with:

C:\Users\Standalone\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\heatmap\ and C:\Users\Standalone\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\heatmap\heatmap.py

But it doesn't work. Can anyone explain to me how to get around this?

My system stuff: Windowns 7 32bit, Python 3.4.3 as part of the Anaconda installation.

Comment: As you can see [from the sources](https://github.com/jjguy/heatmap/blob/master/heatmap/heatmap.py#L60), the module is looking for a file named `cHeatmap-x86.dll` (or something similar, depending on the platform). Do you have such file? Where is it? Also, what does *"having installed via the zipfile"* mean? What zipfile? Have you just copied the files or have you run the `setup.py` script?

Comment: If related to a path-setting it's not the PYTHONPATH that's interresting, it's the search path for `.dll` files. You should check that the mentioned dll is present there.

Comment: To answer the questions:
1) To install I downloaded and unzipped the zip file and ran python setup.py install from my downloads directory
2) cHeatmap-x86.dll wasn't in the installed heatmap file to begin with but I copied it over from the contents of the zipfile and still got the error

Comment: @Tom: `cHeatmap-x86.dll` (unfortunately) is not a Python extension module, so it won't be looked up using `sys.path`. You should place it where Windows looks for DLL files.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need `cHeatmap-x86.dll` to be in your `PYTHONPATH` so, while heatmap is there, according to the source, you'll need an additional dll to be loaded in order for it to work correctly.

I'm not sure how you installed it, and glancing briefly at the source seems to indicate that the author is aware of this issue and tries to solve it when he packages the product. Anyway, you basically just need to add `cHeatmap-x86.dll` somewhere in your `PYTHONPATH`. This could be anywhere from your site-packages, to the current directory.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I ran: 

sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\Standalone\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\heatmap\\cHeatmap-x64.dll')

but still get the error unfortunately. Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: Don't add the actual dll into your sys.path. You should add the directory where the dll is located. (In your case 'C:\\Users\\Standalone\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\heatmap\\')

Comment: No I'm afraid it didn't - I ended up installing a file from a separate fork on Github in the end!